# How to implement HighChart thousandsSep() for android(JAVA) on Hi-chart WordCloud

Tags: java, android, highcharts, word-cloud

I would like to show tooltip on clicking on any word of Android Hi-chart Word-Cloud like **1,000** , currently it is showing like **1 000**.

[image: Kindly notice the attachment]

I had conversation with *Hi-chart support team*. 
They suggested with [this](https://api.highcharts.com/android/highcharts/com/highsoft/highcharts/Common/HIChartsClasses/HILang.html#thousandsSep) URL.

But unable to understand how to implement the same. I tried as below:

```
HILang hiLang = new HILang();
    hiLang.setThousandsSep("3");
```

But setThousandsSep method accepts String type parameter only.

Comment: please post little more code regarding chart generation.

Answer (score 0):

The default is a single space character which is why it is being shown as `3 100`; a space after "3"

Try

```
hiLang.setThousandsSep(",");
```

Comment: The answer is almost correct, you have to also add `hiLang` to `hiChartView.lang` -> `hiChartView.lang = hiLang;`